# Spectrum.js target single selector for event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

This sounds ridiculous, but I can't for the life of me figure how or what to target to create a simple click event.

http://jsfiddle.net/ctkY3/2740/

I hid the sp-dd element. What I want to do is when you click the red portion (or any portion, really), the click event initiates displaying the sp-dd. I'm I completely missing something?

```
$('.sp-preview-inner').on('click', function(){
  $('.sp-dd').css('display', 'block');
})
```

This doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need any Javascript for this. Just add css like below

```
.sp-dd {
  display: none;
}
.sp-active .sp-dd{
    display: block;
}
```

See the fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/ctkY3/2742/

Comment: ahhh, sorry, i totally goofed on that. i was actually displaying block (but wrote 'none'). thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Is this what you need?